# How to reverse this php code "pack("L", 1000);"?

Tags: php, binary, int, binary-data, pack

I have a code that look like this:

```
echo bin2hex( pack( "L", 1000 ) );
```

Which prints: `e8030000`

Now, having only `e8030000`, how can I reverse it back to the int 1000 ?

**UPDATE:**

found the answer: `unpack( "L", ( pack( "H*", 'e8030000' ) ) );`

Comment: You can answer your own questions.

Comment: @Manhim : Not really yet, I have to wait 8 hours because I have < 100 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** `unpack( "L", ( pack( "H*", 'e8030000' ) ) );`